# Acces an array list from another class to use in method

Tags: java, object, arraylist, methods

I am trying to get an arraylist of objects from another class to display it an modify it (delete object in ArrayList) so the original ArrayList has to be modified also...I have tried the method below whitout success.

Class Atribute

```
private int number; //user imput
```

Methods

```
public String DisplayObj() {
    String result;
    FormularioPedido form = new FormularioPedido(); //instance of the other class so I can access the arrayList
    ArrayList<Pedido> lista = form.getListaPedido();

    number -= 1;
    Pedido pedido = lista.get(number);
    result = pedido.getTamanio() + pedido.getIngredientesToString()
            + pedido.getBebida() + pedido.getExtra() + pedido.getCelular();
    return result;
}

public void deleteObj() {

    FormularioPedido form = new FormularioPedido();
    List<Pedido> lista = form.getListaPedido();

    number -= 1;
    lista.remove(number);

}
```

Comment: You are recreating `new FormularioPedido();` every time. Try making it a global(class) variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the lista as a Class attribut.
That way the list you are displaying will be the same as the one you are deleting from.

At the moment it's 2 separates lists and everytime you call the display method you recreate one.

```
private int number; //user imput
private FormularioPedido form  = new FormularioPedido();

public String DisplayObj() {
    String result;
    ArrayList<Pedido> lista = form.getListaPedido();

    number -= 1;
    Pedido pedido = lista.get(number);
    result = pedido.getTamanio() + pedido.getIngredientesToString()
            + pedido.getBebida() + pedido.getExtra() + pedido.getCelular();
    return result;
}

public void deleteObj() {

    List<Pedido> lista = form.getListaPedido();

    number -= 1;
    lista.remove(number);
}
```

Of course you would need to check for the list size before doing delete or display as to avoid exception.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you write `new FormularioPedido()`, you create a new list (returned when you call to the `form.getListaPedido()`). You should think a little more about your class design. For example, the list could be a class attribute and you could opperate over the same list instance.